# py2exe - paramiko, ImportError: No module named paramiko

Tags: python, py2exe, paramiko

im trying to compile my application whit py2exe, setup.py code :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")

setup( options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1, "optimize": 2,"dll_excludes": "w9xpopen.exe", "ascii": 0, "bundle_files": 1}},
       zipfile = None,
       console = [
        {
            "script": "app.py",      
            "icon_resources": [(0, "favicon.ico")]
        }
    ],)
```

compilation working whitout problem, bat if try start app.exe, give this error :

```
F:\python\app\dist>app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

line 8 off my app is this :

```
import paramiko
```

how can resolve this problem ? need compile my application whit py2exe for distribute !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put import paramiko into your setup.py as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.answermysearches.com/making-py2exe-work-with-paramiko/437/) might offer a possible approach solving the problem:

> When running py2exe with a script importing Paramiko I noticed this in
>   the output:
>
> The following modules appear to be missing ... paramiko ...
>
> And then in the log file created when I run the exe I saw this:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):  ... ImportError: No module named
>   paramiko This has to do with py2exe not being able to handle egg
>   files. So what I did is  pulled out the paramiko directory from the
>   egg, and placed that in my site-packages  directory, and then deleted
>   the egg. It works now though the setup function still  tells me this:
>
> The following modules appear to be missing
>   ['Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath', 'Crypto.Util.winrandom', '_ssl',
>   'r_hmac']
>
> Luckily as far as I can tell, I don’t use those modules anywhere.